# xmpp stream did disconnect in ios

Tags: ios, iphone, xmppframework

I am working on a chat app with XMPP server. I have successfully implement the MUC in my app and everything is working perfect but sometime my connection to XMPP server goes down and `xmppStreamDidDisconnect:withError:` delegate calls with the following error.

```
Error Domain=GCDAsyncSocketErrorDomain Code=4 "Read operation timed out" UserInfo=0x1d315c90 {NSLocalizedDescription=Read operation timed out}
```

Can anybody help me whether the problem is in my internet connection or at server side?

Comment: The error in authenticate your username and password. So  authenticate with valid username and password.

Comment: HI I am also facing same issue did you found any solution.

Comment: @Parthpatel1105 in my case didAuthenticate also not calling even non of xmpp methods are calling except above delegate.